# The char* constant value ERROR with GNU G++ compiler

Tags: c++

I write sevaral files with the relationship like:

file A.h:

```
#ifndef MACRO_HEADER
#define MACRO_HEADER
const char* CONST_CHAR_NAME = "name";
#endif
```

file B.h(B.cpp) and file C.h(C.cpp) also include this common type definition header A.h.
When the g++ finally combines the obj files to lib, it gives out he redefinition error.I confess that I make a mistake and I should define the constant as:

```
const char* const CONST_CHAR_NAME = "name"; //This is OK
```

But why compiler gives me a redefinition ERROR? Is const char* not a constant value?But I use typeid.name to check the types of `const char *` and  `cosnt char* const`. They are the same:**char const *** . I am confused with the ERROR.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're defining the same variable name in multiple places, i.e. every source file that includes the .h.

You can eliminate the linker errors by declaring each definition to be local to the source file using the `static` keyword:

```
static const char* CONST_CHAR_NAME = "name";
```

Comment: Thanks ,one more question: Is that means const char* a variable, and const char* const a constant?

Comment: @MIKU_LINK, there are two things here that `const` can be applied to - the pointer itself, and the `char`s that the pointer point to. Usually it's redundant to make the pointer itself `const` because you don't try to change it in practice.

Answer (score 1):

It gives errors because `CONST_CHAR_NAME` is *defined* in multiple "translation units" (a translation unit is basically a single source file and all included header files). You have to *declare* it `extern` then in one source file *define* the constant.

So in the header file:

```
extern const char* CONST_CHAR_NAME;
```

And in **one** source file:

```
const char* CONST_CHAR_NAME = "name";
```

**Edit:** Difference between `const char*` and `const char* const`

The declaration

```
const char* CONST_CHAR_NAME;
```

creates a pointer to a constant string. You can assign to it, as long as it points to a constant string. I.e. both lines below are okay:

```
CONST_CHAR_NAME = "foo";
CONST_CHAR_NAME = "bar";
```

On the other hand you have

```
const char* const CONST_CHAR_NAME;
```

The above create a constant pointer to a constant string. This means you can not assign to the pointer again, so the two assignments above are *not* okay.

Comment: Thank you!That's right,but , I want `CONST_CHAR_NAME` to act like constant just as `const int` or enumerator which can define in header file and be used in many source files. Is that means that `const char*` is still a variable?

Comment: @MIKU_LINK Added some describing text to the answer.

Comment: Thank you!The difference of const char* and char* const really matters.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you should declare it as:

```
const char CONST_CHAR_NAME[] = "name";
```

Comment: Eh, if it's `const`, it doesn't make too much of a difference. The difference between `char *str = "string";` and `char[] str = "string";`  matters, however.

Comment: Thanks. Is array form more typical? I will follow this style.